# It´s necessary to create different screens sizes and density xmls for an app? Best approach for this

Tags: user-interface, layout

Just a straight forward question. I´m trying to make the best possible choice here and there is too much information for a "semi-beginner" like me.

Well, at this point, I´m trying with screen size values for my layout `(activity_main.xml (normal, large, small))` and with different densities (`xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `mhdpi`) and, if a can say so myself, it is a mess. Do I have to create every possible option to support all screen sizes and densities? Or am I doing something really wrong here? what is the best approach for this?
My layouts are now `activity_main(normal_land_xxhdpi)` and I have serious doubts about it.

I´m using last version of android studio of course. My app is a single activity with buttons, textview and others. Does not have any fragments or intents whatsoever, and for that reason I think this has to be an easy task, but not for me.

Hope you guys can help. I don't think i need to put any code here, but if needed, i can add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a responsive UI for every device you need to learn about some things first:

-Difference between PX, DP:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Here you can understand that dp is a standard measure which android uses to calculate how much pixels, lets say a line, should have to keep the proportions between different screensizes with different densities.

-Resolution, Density and Ratio:

The resolution is how much pixels a screen has over height and width. This pixels can be smaller or bigger, so for instance, if you have a screen A with 10x10 px whose pixels are two times smaller than other screen B with 10 x 10 pixels too, A is two times smaller than B even when both have 10 x 10 px.

For that reason exists the meaning **Density**, which is how much pixels your screen has for every inch, so you can measure the quality of a screen where most pixels per inch (ppi) is better.

Ratio tells you how much pixels are for height as well as width, for example the ratio of a screen of 1000 x 2000 px is 1:2, a full hd screen of 1920 x 1080 is 16:9 (16 pixels height for every 9 pixels width). A 1:1 ratio is a square screen.

-Standard device's resolutions

You can find the most common measurements on...

https://material.io/resources/devices/

When making a UI, you use the DP measurements. You will realize that even when resolution between screens are different, the DP is the same cause they have different densities.

Now, the right way is going with constraint layout using dp measures to put your views on screen, with correct constraints the content will adapt to other screen sizes

Anyway, you will need to make additional XML for some cases:

-Different orientation
-Different ratio
-Different  DP resolution (not px)

For every activity, you need to provide a portrait and landscape design. If other device has different ratio, maybe you will need to adjust the height or width due to the proportions of the screens aren't the same. Finally, even if the ratio is the same, the DP resolution could be different, maybe you designed an activity for a 640x360dp and other device has 853x480dp, which means you will have more vertical space.

You can read more here:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

And learn how to use constraintLayout correctly:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?hl=es-419

Note:
Maybe it seems to be so much work for every activity, but you make the first design and then you just need to copy the design to other xml with some qualifiers and change the dp values to adjust the views as you wants (without making from scratch) which is really faster.

Comment: Man, thank you for taking your time to answer. This is what i thought, more or less, but i guess i needed confirmation and an explanation from someone who really know about this stuff and, of course, i did not know about the importance of some of what you´ve told me. I´m trying to learn the right way, if there is one, so i´m really grateful. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome! One last thing, please check my answer as correct if it answered what you needed, you will help me so much and also other people who have the same doubt.